# How to count number of requests in spring boot app?

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot application whose metrics I want to later send to gcp. But for now I just need to find a way to count the total number of requests my application is handling either with `actuator` or with `micrometer`. Does anybody know how I could do something like this? Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Spring Boot Actuator - HttpTrace](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/html/#http-trace)

It's not enabled in the latest versions by default but you can do so by implementing `HttpTraceRepository`.

In this repository you can use a counter to measure the number of requests, then add it to the MetricRegistry. Another option would be to use a filter and then use a counter there.

Answer (score 1):

A `spring-actuator` example:

```xml
//add pom
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

using the actuator

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(
  ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http.authorizeExchange()
      .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
      .anyExchange().authenticated()
      .and().build();
}
```

Then you can get the data from http://localhost:8080/metrics

check more from the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-enabling)

Answer (score 0):

U can add Spring Boot Actuator and Micrometer dependencies

application.properties

```
management.metrics.enable.http.server.requests=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Maven:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Include a Micrometer registry of your choice -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
  implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-core'
  implementation 'io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus'
}
```

If your runs on localhost:8080 use this

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics
```

> "application.ready.time", "application.started.time", "disk.free",
> "disk.total", "executor.active", "executor.completed",
> "executor.pool.core", "executor.pool.max", "executor.pool.size",

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus
```

> spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findFirstByTitle",repository="NewsArticleRepository",state="SUCCESS",}
> 10.0 spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_sum{exception="None",method="findFirstByTitle",repository="NewsArticleRepository",state="SUCCESS",}
> 0.0931051 spring_data_repository_invocations_seconds_count{exception="None",method="findByOrderByPublishedAtDesc",repository="NewsArticleRepository",state="SUCCESS",}
> 1.0 and .....

```
http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics/http.server.requests
```

> "name": "http.server.requests", "baseUnit": "seconds", "measurements":
> [   {
> "statistic": "COUNT",
> "value": 20.0   },   {
> "statistic": "TOTAL_TIME",
> "value": 2.0688337   },   {
> "statistic": "MAX",
> "value": 0.0   } ],